# why is pymongo requiring sudo to pip install?

Tags: python, mongodb, ubuntu, pip, pymongo

why is pymongo requiring sudo for install? Its docs don't mention anything about sudo...

```
(myapp) cchilders:~/projects/app (master) 
$ sudo pip3 uninstall pymongo 
  Successfully uninstalled pymongo-3.3.0
The directory '/home/cchilders/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.


(myapp) cchilders:~/projects/app (master) 
$ pip3 install pymongo
Collecting pymongo
  Using cached pymongo-3.3.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: pymongo
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 287, in clobber
    ensure_dir(dest)  # common for the 'include' path
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages'

(myapp) cchilders:~/projects/app (master) 
$ sudo pip3 install pymongo 
The directory '/home/cchilders/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/cchilders/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pymongo
  Downloading pymongo-3.3.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (337kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 337kB 1.5MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pymongo
Successfully installed pymongo-3.3.0
```

perms are the same here and any other:

```
drwxrwxr-x 6 cchilders cchilders 4096 Sep 24 19:42 myapp
-rw-r--r-- 1 cchilders cchilders   96 Feb 23  2016 initialize
drwxrwxr-x 6 cchilders cchilders 4096 Apr 21 16:19 knockoutjs_official_tutorial
drwxrwxr-x 6 cchilders cchilders 4096 Apr  3 10:38 my_scripting_library
drwxrwxr-x 8 cchilders cchilders 4096 Sep 15 03:41 neo4j_sandbox
```

Thank you

Comment: In general any package will require sudo to be installed into a systemwide Python library directory.  You could use a virtualenv if you don't want to do that.

Comment: the virtualenv is active..

Comment: question format has been fixed

Comment: Did you chain your virtual environment off the system Python ``site-packages`` directory. This is generally regarded as bad practice and you will have problems if ``pip`` tries to upgrade a package which is actually in the system packages directory, even though your intent is to install new version in the virtual environment. In your case though it looks like things are further confused by having packages install in your per user ``site-packages`` as well.

Comment: i didn't do that on purpose...so how do I fix?

Answer (score 1):

Check your virtual environment ownership. If your don't have write permission to that path, you will need `sudo`

Comment: ok, but how do I do that? check perms of the path to bin/python?

Comment: @codyc4321 check your virtual environment. that's the path you type when you create virtual environment.

Comment: the main folder or the pip? the main folder and pip both have write access for user cchilders